# Preventing infinite loop data retrieval with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I was wondering: Imagine a scenario where e.g.

//POJO

```
public class User {

   private String userName;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private List<Blog> blogList;

   //All getters and setters are found here and assume they're generated.
}

public class Blog {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private User author;
    private Date datePublished;
    private Date dateLastModified;

    //All getters and setters have been generated (by Eclipse or NetBeans)
}
```

Imagine that these objects have been correctly mapped into their respective Hibernate configuration files.

My question:

How would I retrieve my user with the list of all the user blogs on code level? (i.e., not allow hibernate to populate `blogList` automatically for me. 
I want to add paging (i.e. from list 5, retrieve 20 list) and also, if you think carefully, this might be an infinite loop as a Blog has a `User` entity which has a `List<Blog>` entity.

How do I prevent this?

**PS** Just out of curiousity, how would I let Hibernate populate my `blogList` on the configuration side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Hibernate detects such loops and doesn't let them happen
- You can mark your collection with fetch type=lazy (`fetchType=FetchType.LAZY`) so that the collection elements are not fetched when the owning object is
- you can used a `Query` with `setFirstResult(..)` and `setMaxResults(..)` in order to achieve paging. (and get rid of the collection then)

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds.  Nice.

Comment: I get what you mean, so I guess it's bye, bye DAO's :)

Comment: What does `FetchType.LAZY` do?

Comment: it is by no means "bye" to DAOs. The DAOs use the session/entity manager, Query objects, etc. The service layer should not know of these. FetchType.LAZY means that collection is fetched only if it is accessed.

Comment: OK...so would Hibernate know if the collection is accessed? by the `getBlogList()` method?

Comment: it creates a proxy around your list. So it becomes `PersistentList`, instead of `ArrayList` for example.

Comment: I'm beginning to like Hibernate now.